# How to disable login screen

Tags: joomla-3.4, user-groups

A web developer designed my site so that to get to a certain area in my site a user will need to login with a username and password.

I can't see how the developer configured the area so that users have to login first. I want users be able to access the page / area without having to login, but not sure where I need to make the change.

Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that your developer configured one or more menu items or articles to be available to restricted users only (or another custom user group).

You can edit this by going to **Menus** -> **[YOUR MENU]**. You'll see something like this:

[image: Menu item access control]

This is called access control, and anything different than `Public` will require username/password in order to view.

When editing a menu item, on the right hand side you'll find a drop down list where you can select who can view the menu item.

[image: Menu item access control]

This can also be applied to articles, modules, categories etc., so you'll have to look through your site and see where this has been enabled.

Change settings to `Public` in order to let anyone visit your content.

Comment: Hi Johnapw, I tried everything to public, but I still get the user profie screen requiring me and enter username and password. I'm pretty lost as to what to do. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.